# IIS gives 'Access to the path is denied' - NopCommerce

Tags: iis, iis-10

I'm trying to deploy a NopCommerce application on the IIS server. But I'm getting permission errors.

```
    Application startup exception: System.Exception: Plugin 'Eagle360 Dynamics 365 B2B Services'. Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\B2BDemo\Plugins\bin\Plugin.Dynamics365B2B.Services.dll' is denied.
Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\B2BDemo\Plugins\bin\Plugin.Dynamics365B2B.Services.dll' is denied.
```

I tried many user permissions. but still no luck.

[image][image]

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**

Please follow below steps, and don't worry I just want know whether it will work fine if we use administrator account. If it works, we can make sure, you site and publish file is fine. And this problem is permission issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Please try to copy and paste the content to other `Drive`, like `D:/` or `E:/`.

From your error message, it seems you need add `Physical Path Credentials` if you don't want to use other `Drive`.

[image]

Comment: As you say I tried it E:// drive. And Physical Path Credentials set to 'Application user(pass-through authentication)'.    but no luck..

Comment: These images no longer work. What are the steps??